# Name Generator Problem: How can I modify the code to provide multiple (e.g. 20) name options for each criteria I specify

Tags: python, python-3.x

## This program generates random baby names using parameters such as the length of the name and random generators for string function

I have tried creating a loop on the `return name.capitalize()` as well as looping around the final output `print(name1.name_gen())`

```
import random, string

# Create a class for Baby Name
class Baby_name:
    # create an __init__ method which takes in the desired length of the Baby Name
    def __init__(self, name_len):
        self.name_len = name_len


    # create a method within the Baby_name class which asks for user input and generates a random name    
    def name_gen(self):
        # specify variables from letter types vowels & consonants, declare variables name & choice as empty strings to take in values
        vowels = 'aeiou'
        consonants = [con for con in string.ascii_lowercase if con not in vowels]
        name, choice = '', ''

        # loop through a list defined by the range of the name length
        for i in range(1, self.name_len + 1):
            # ask user for input according to the specified variables and loop through random letters within ascii vowels & consonants
            choice = input(f"Select {self.name_len} letter types of your Baby's name 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonant or 'l' for any letter. ENTER LETTER TYPE {i}: ").lower()
            if choice == 'v':
                name += random.choice(vowels)
            elif choice == 'c':
                name += random.choice(consonants)
            else:
                name += random.choice(string.ascii_letters)

        # return the variable name which contains the concartenated letters randomly selected, capitalize the first letter
        return name.capitalize()


# create an instance of the Baby_name class called name1
name1 = Baby_name(int(input("Choose the length of your Baby's name: ")))

# print the output based on the supplied variables of the name1 instance
print(name1.name_gen())
```

Assuming I choose a name length of 4, with criteria set as (vowel,consonant,vowel,vowel). rather than just 1 name i would like the output to display 20 options.

I currently get just one option.

Answer (score 1):

You ask for the pattern once and generate as many names. I removed the `self` references and substituted the name lenght as parameter to the function:

```
import string 
import random

def name_gen(amount, name_len):
    """Generate 'amount' names of 'name_len' specified by the same pattern.""" 
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    consonants = [con for con in string.ascii_lowercase if con not in vowels]
    pattern = []

    for i in range(name_len): 
        choice = input(f"Select {name_len} letter types of your Baby's name 'v' for Vowel, 'c' for consonant or 'l' for any letter. ENTER LETTER TYPE {i+1}: ").lower()
        pattern.append(choice)

    def genName(pattern):
        """Generate a name from a pattern-input of v,c,l. Return capitalized."""
        n = []
        for c in pattern:
            if c == 'v':
                n.append(random.choice(vowels))
            elif c == 'c':
                n.append(random.choice(consonants))
            else:
                n.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
        return ''.join(n).capitalize()        

    return [genName(pattern) for _ in range(amount)]

# print the decomposed list on single lines
print( *name_gen(10,4), sep="\n" )
```

Output:

```
# input pattern: vcll

Izow
Iggm
Uqua
Iqtt
Eknt
Ures        # only one I would consider a "real" name
Iwny
Epct
Axbm
```

Adding incrementally to a string is slow - the shorter string is discarded and a longer one created (strings are immutable) - use a list of chars and *join* it.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your solution. I noticed you implemented it in a nested function. What if I want the functions flat and implemented in the original class. I have tried to adopt your solution this way but with little success. See my code below

Comment: I would also like to option to ask the user for length of the name

Comment: @user and what is your specific problem with that? You already solved getting an integer from a user input. This function accepts a name length input. Combine both and voilá - done... you only need to apply some transfer-knowledge to get from _this_ function to your class instance function.